# How to implement Java step Builder pattern in Kotlin

Tags: android, design-patterns, kotlin

In my current Android project I am investigating the use of Kotlin.
I am rewriting a 100% Java Android app to 100% Kotlin.
I'm stuck with attempting to implement my Java step builders though.

I employed Java step Builders as they force users of my code to supply all required data and/or functions before being able to execute an associated RxJava process.

These RxJava processes are complex and I wished to simplify their initialisation and execution as much as possible.

The use of Java Step builders allow developers to write the following code:-

```
Sequence.builder()
    .stepOne(one)
    .stepTwo(two)
    .stepThree(three)
    .build()
    .execute();
```

What I am looking for is a Kotlin version of this approach.
My initial thought was that Kotlin would support Builders and Step Builders.

I am not "precious" about employing Builders in Kotlin, the Kotlin solution must force the developers that use my code to have supplied all required data and/or functions before they are able to execute the associated "executed" code.

From investigating Kotlin I've discovered internal DSLs which are sounding both interesting topic in themselves and a possible solution to this particular question.

I have a number of Step Builders to implement, none of these have more than 6 parameters. I do like to try and keep to SOLID no more than three parameters rule though.

Also if it makes any difference, some of the passed parameters are RxJava Actions and Consumers. Default values are not relevant here as none of the parameters have viable default values.

UPDATE

My Java step builders all resemble this:-

```
public class ExampleSequence extends Sequence {

    private static final String TAG = "ExampleSequence";

    private final Action onComplete;
    private final Consumer<? super Throwable> onError;

    /**
     * @param builder
     */
    private ExampleSequence(final Builder builder) {
        super(builder.getDoLoginRefreshFail());
        this.onError = builder.getOnError();
        this.onComplete = builder.getOnComplete();
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public static OnCompleteAction builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public interface OnCompleteAction {
        onErrorAction onComplete(@NonNull final Action onComplete);
    }

    public interface onErrorAction {
        DoLoginRefreshFail onError(@NonNull final Consumer<? super Throwable> onError);
    }

    public interface DoLoginRefreshFail {
        Build doLoginRefreshFail(@NonNull final Action doLoginRefreshFail);
    }

    public interface Build {
        ExampleSequence build();
    }

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    public void execute() {
        final AtomicInteger retryCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);

        final Observable<Response<GraphqlQueryResponse>> feedArticles = getPageAndNextInboxArticles(offset, limit)
                .onErrorResumeNext(manufactureResumeNext())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

        final Observable<Response<GraphqlQueryResponse>> readingListArticles = getPageAndReadingListArticles(readingListoffset, limit)
                .onErrorResumeNext(manufactureResumeNext())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

        login()
                .flatMap(...)
                .ignoreElement()
                .andThen(...)
                .andThen(...)
                .ignoreElements()
                .andThen(...)
                .flattenAsObservable(x -> x)
                .flatMapCompletable(...)
                .retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(e -> constructRetryHandler(retryCounter, e)))
                .doOnComplete(onComplete)
                .doOnError(onError)
                .doAfterTerminate(doAfterTerminate())
                .doOnSubscribe(compositeDisposable::add)
                .blockingAwait();
    }

    /**********************************************************************************
     *
     * BUILDER
     *
     */
    public static class Builder implements OnCompleteAction, onErrorAction, DoLoginRefreshFail, Build {

        private Action onComplete;
        private Consumer<? super Throwable> onError;
        private Action doLoginRefreshFail;

        /***********************************************************************
         *
         */
        @Override
        public ExampleSequence build() {
            return new ExampleSequence(this);
        }

        @Override
        public onErrorAction onComplete(@NonNull final Action onComplete) {
            this.onComplete = onComplete;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public DoLoginRefreshFail onError(@NonNull final Consumer<? super Throwable> onError) {
            this.onError = onError;
            return this;
        }


        @Override
        public Build doLoginRefreshFail(@NonNull final Action doLoginRefreshFail) {
            this.doLoginRefreshFail = doLoginRefreshFail;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * @return the onError
         */
        Consumer<? super Throwable> getOnError() {
            return onError;
        }

        /**
         * @return the onComplete
         */
        Action getOnComplete() {
            return onComplete;
        }

        Action getDoLoginRefreshFail() {
            return doLoginRefreshFail;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many parameters do you have for the builder? Normally I would just use a constructor or a factory function with default parameters and call it with named parameters.

Comment: can you at least share your java code?

Comment: @andylamax yes, I can share... Once I'm at my office 

Comment: I haven't downvoted you, but for this to be a better question, you should be explaining why you think Java offers something that Kotlin doesn't. You're not relying on any particular Java language feature here, and it's not clear what you feel is the barrier to creating the same implementation in Kotlin.

Comment: @RobPridham .  I do not think Java offers something that Kotlin doesn't... I do not know enough about Kotlin to state that. I am looking for solutions of migrating my Java code to Kotlin while keeping control over all related data and functions being populated before allowing my "execute" method to be called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The step builder pattern in Kotlin is completely doable, and I've provided an example of it that mirrors the Java example you provided.

```
class ExampleSequence private constructor(builder: Builder): Sequence(builder.doLoginRefreshFail) { //This is your "super()" call.

    //This is equivalent to assigning the final variables [onComplete] and [onError] in the class constructor
    private val onComplete = builder.onComplete
    private val onError = builder.onError

    //More info about companion objects here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects
    companion object {

        //Java will see this as [ExampleSequence.Companion.builder()] unless you add this annotation
        @JvmStatic
        fun builder(): OnCompleteAction = Builder()
    }


    fun execute() {
        //Do your stuff here...
    }

    //The following classes and interfaces are similar to being static inner classes. If you want the classes to access
    //fields of the enclosing outer class, you must use the keyword [inner] before declaring the class. Example:
    // inner class Foo { ... }

    interface OnCompleteAction {
        fun onComplete(onComplete: Action): onErrorAction
    }

    interface DoLoginRefreshFail {
        fun doLoginRefreshFail(doLoginRefreshFail: Action): Build
    }

    interface onErrorAction {
        fun onError(onError: Consumer<in Throwable>): DoLoginRefreshFail //The [in] keyword is the same as saying Consumer<? super Throwable>
    }

    interface Build {
        fun build(): ExampleSequence
    }

    class Builder: OnCompleteAction, onErrorAction, DoLoginRefreshFail, Build {

        //The [lateinit] keyword states that this variable will be initialized later. Calling it before it is initialized will throw an exception
        lateinit var onComplete: Action
            private set //Only this class can modify.

        lateinit var onError: Consumer<in Throwable>
            private set

        lateinit var doLoginRefreshFail: Action
            private set

        //No special differences here... oooh, inlined [override] keyword!
        override fun onComplete(onComplete: Action): onErrorAction {
            this.onComplete = onComplete
            return this
        }

        override fun doLoginRefreshFail(doLoginRefreshFail: Action): Build {
            this.doLoginRefreshFail = doLoginRefreshFail
            return this
        }

        override fun onError(onError: Consumer<in Throwable>): DoLoginRefreshFail {
            this.onError = onError
            return this
        }

        override fun build(): ExampleSequence = ExampleSequence(this)

        //Where are the getter methods? If you look at the variable declarations, they are public by default.
        //This means that these variables are public read, but can only be set by this class only. In other words, built-in getter!
    }
}
```

However, in a pure Kotlin project, step builder is sort of an anti-pattern. With default and named parameters built into the language, you can actually achieve SOLID by a simple data class. Taking the `ExampleSequence` class for example, your solution could look something like:

```
data class ExampleSequence(
        private val onComplete: Action,
        private val onError: Consumer<in Throwable>,
        private val doLoginRefreshFail: Action,
        private val aNewParam: String = "Default")
    : Sequence(doLoginRefreshFail) { //This is your "super()" call.

    fun execute() {
        //Do your stuff here...
    }
}

fun foo() {
    //Example of using named parameters and passing in variables. Notice parameters aren't in the same order as how it is declared in the class
    ExampleSequence(
            onError = Consumer(),
            onComplete = Action(),
            doLoginRefreshFail = Action()
    ).execute()

    //Since I added [aNewParam], instead of using the default, let's change it.
    ExampleSequence(
            onError = Consumer(),
            onComplete = Action(),
            doLoginRefreshFail = Action(),
            aNewParam = "Something else!"
    ).execute()
}
```

Here is a nice article going into a bit more detail: https://dev.to/chrisvasqm/avoiding-the-builder-design-pattern-in-kotlin-3b1a

Also, in case you need another example of a step builder pattern in Kotlin, you might want to check this out too: https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-builder-pattern

Comment: nice work. Thanks for the additional links. Could I also try TypeSafe DSL as a step builders replacement?

Comment: That could definitely be done, but if you're only providing components in a shallow builder, I'd just stick with data classes. Here's an article that popped up in my Medium feed just today that I think you might be interested in: https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/write-your-android-networking-as-a-kotlin-dsl-330febae503f